# Creating P2P Connections with Wi-Fi on Android

Tags: java, android, p2p, android-wifi, wifi-direct

So I'm trying to create p2p connection work on android.
And I am stuck on following part. code below is what's provided on API and it does not make sense to me. I feel like there must be a type for a mManager and the type is not given. 
How do I make this Work?

Link to API:
http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html

```
@Override
Channel mChannel;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    mManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);

    mChannel = mManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a feeling you imported the wrong Channel. You may have imported

```
java.nio.Channels.Channel
```

when the one you want is

```
android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I used [alljoin](https://www.alljoyn.org/docs-and-downloads/android) in my project. This api very successfully communicate two devices.

Answer (score 0):

The type you are looking for is:

```
WifiP2pManager manager;
```